# Möbius transformation: proving the image of the unit circle is a line

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Problem**

1) Find the Möbius transformation which maps the points $0,i,-i$ to $0,1,\infty$ respectively.

2) Prove that the image of the circle centered at $0$, of radius $1$ is the line $\{Re(z)\}=1$.

In $1)$ I didn't have problems, the homographic transformation $T(z)$ which satisfies the conditions given is $T(z)=\dfrac{2z}{z+i}$.

I don't know how to solve $(2)$. If I denote the circle by $C$, I want to show that $T(C)=\{Re(z)=1\}$. I've tried to prove the two inclusions of these sets but I couldn't, I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Another, more abstract approach is available if you know that Mobius transformations take (generalized) circles to (generalized) circles: you know that at least one point on your circle maps to infinity, so you know the result must be _some_ line; you know that $i$ maps to $1$ so you know the line runs through $z=1$.  Now, pick any other point on your circle (say, $z=-1$) and look at where it maps to: $T(-1) = \frac2{1-i} = 1+i$, so the line is the line through $z=1$ and $z=1+i$ - in other words, the line $\Re(z)=1$.

Comment: Yesterday I've read Ahlfors proof about this so yes, I could have used that but it didn't occur to me, very useful comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element of $C$ is $e^{it}$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$T(e^{it})=\frac{2e^{it}}{e^{it}+i}=\frac{2e^{it}(e^{-it}-i)}{2+2\sin(t)}=\frac{2-2ie^{it}}{2+2\sin(t)}=\frac{1-i(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))}{1+\sin(t)}=$$
$$=\frac{1+\sin(t)-i\cos(t)}{1+\sin(t)}=1-i\frac{\cos(t)}{1+\sin(t)}\ .$$
This is a parametrization of the line $Re(z)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just don't understand two steps of your solution: why $\frac{2e^{it}}{e^{it}+i}=\frac{2e^{it}(e^{-it}-i)}{2+2\sin(t)}$? and I see that $1+-i\dfrac{\cos(t)}{1+\sin(t)}$ are points that belong to $\{Re(z)=1\}$, but what if, for example I pick the point $1+i20$ in that line? My doubt is if this parametrization is of the line itself or of a subset of the line.

Comment: The first equality you mentioned comes from multiplying numerator and denominator by $(e^{-it}-i)$, this in order to get a real denominator. Actually  to get the whole line you don't need all the real $t$'s, but just say from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ (you are on the circle). You can see that between these values you pass from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: @user156441 If you know the half-angle formulas, you can reduce the expression: $\frac{\cos t}{1+\sin t} = \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$ (where $\theta=\frac\pi2-t$) $=\tan\frac\theta2$.  This should make it clear that the range is precisely all of $\mathbb{R}$.